When/why to use a power source selection switch?
I'm designing an automotive device that will be taking power from the car's battery. It also has a USB port that will be primarily used for firmware updates and possibly datalogging down the line. I have a 5V buck converter, the 5V rail is used by CAN transceivers, a LCD backlight, and feeds a 3.3V LDO. The 3.3V rail is used by the logic devices.
I often see a power selection switch, something like in the schematic I drew here, used in this type of scenario where there are two possible power sources in order to disconnect one source while they're both connected. Here, I would only be using USB power when the battery power is not available. What's the advantage of having a power selection switch like this as opposed to plumbing the USB 5V directly to the output of the buck converter? Is there any reason I shouldn't connect the USB 5V directly to the 5V rail and forego the power selection switch?

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab

First of all, you can't connect two power supplies together. At least, not without facing the possible consequenes of fried equipment. Second is, it would violate USB specs.
Assuming your USB implementation is a device, intended to be connected to USB Host like a PC, there are already multiple problems.
If you just connect your USB connector and regulator output together, it allows the USB connector to back-feed 5V into your laptop. Which is a problem especially if the laptop is off. It may damage the USB port protection and power components.
A related issue is that your 5V regulator may damage if it is not powered from the input side and you simply short circuit external 5V from USB to the regulator output.
A secondary issue is that then your device cannot determine if it has been connected to a host laptop or not. USB devices are required to detect when USB Host applies 5V power to use the port, so that the USB Device can then start advertizing it's speed and presence by pulling up one of the data lines to 3.3V. If the PC is off and does not provide 5V supply, the Device must not pull any of the data lines high.

Thanks for the reply. Is the MOSFET switch I illustrated an adequate solution to protecting the PC? Would you recommend something similar of the output of the regulator if it does not internally have some sort of protection to that issue?

Can you guarantee at 100% that there the battery will always be disconnected when the USB is plugged in?
If not, some users will plug both at once (even if you write a warning in big red letters directly next to the connectors).
So make sure that plugging in both connected at once won't cause any damage, unless you are going for really low cost, or you physically prevent both connections to be done simultaneous (for example because the plugs would overlap), or you have a piece of plastic always blocking one position (that slides between the 2 positions, always blocking one).
Also note that if connecting 2 "5V" supplies together, they will never have exactly the same voltage : it can lead to huge currents (basically, it's a short circuit between for example 5.2V and 4.8V).
As Justme noted, backfeeding 5V into the USB is probably not allowed. And the other way, you need to check that the regulator accepts to be fed 5V at the output without input voltage.
If you want to go low cost, and can accept a voltage drop on your 5V, then you can do a diode OR-ing between the 5V from the regulator and the 5V from USB. But you will get something like 4.5V at the output (up to you if this is OK or not).

No, I can't guarantee that. As a matter of fact I would like users to be able to have both connected at the same time without issue. Is the MOSFET solution I illustrated an adequate solution to "disconnecting" the 2 supplies?
